# How to migrate Azure VM with large disk

Tags: azure, data-migration

I tried to migrate a VM to a different region using disaster recovery, but got this error message.

The selected virtual machines have one or more data disks with size greater than 8192 GB which is currently not supported.

How can this VM be migrated to a different region?

Answer (score 0):

The supported maximum size is 8192 GB for the managed data disks when you replicate VM via disaster recovery, read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/site-recovery/azure-to-azure-support-matrix#replicated-machines---storage).

As a workaround, you could generalize the Azure VM then [create a managed image of a generalized VM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/capture-image-resource#create-an-image-of-a-vm-using-powershell) in the current VM region. Also, you could share images between regions via [Shared Image Gallery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/shared-image-galleries). Then you could create an Azure VM from the image in another region.

Another option is to Copy an Azure VM From Region A to Region B with PowerShell, you could get details from [this blog](https://www.obungi.com/2017/07/21/how-to-copy-an-azure-vm-from-region-a-to-region-b/).

Hope this could help you.